# css file Causing http exception

Tags: css, http

I have a css file that dictates max screen size for mobile devices. However when my page is hit i receive [image]

I thought about making a change in the web config like so

```
<httpruntime requestvalidationmode="2.0">
             requestPathInvalidCharacters="*,&,\"
             relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
             /></httpruntime>
```

But i dont know if this is the best way to go. Here is what my css file looks like.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Phone */
@import url("phone.css") only screen and (max-width:320px);

/* iPhone */
@import url("iphone.css") only screen and (max-device-width:480px);

/* Tablet */
@import url("tablet.css") only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px);
/* Desktop */
@import url("desktop.css") only screen and (min-width:769px);
```

How do i prevent this error. My log file is pointing at the rule in this page for max screen size and saying that the ":" character is the problem.

Comment: Something is using ":" for a path somewhere. So instead of "http​​​​​​​​​​:​​​​​/​​​​​/​​​​​domain/whatever​​​​​" you get ":". I'm not sure what is causing it, but one thing I'd check would be the unescaped ampersand in the config file.